# What do the numbers in a multi-part email mean?

Tags: email, multipart

I'm looking at the source of a multi-part message from Thunderbird (in hopes of writing my own multi-part message from C++/Javascript)

I was wondering what the follow means (the part between the text-only part and the html part of the email) and how I might calculate it for my own program to generate a multi-part email:

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_32252.1057009685.31.001
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_32252.1057009685.31.002"
Content-Description: Message in alternative text and HTML forms


------=_NextPart_32252.1057009685.31.002
```

(as seen [here](http://mailformat.dan.info/headers/mime.html))

The rest of the message code makes sense to me for the post part.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The numbers you are seeing within the boundary delimiters don't necessarily mean anything** (although the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt) doesn't preclude an implementor from trying to include some meaning).

They must be unique and not contained within the part that they encapsulate.

From [**RFC 2046**](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt):

> **5.1.  Multipart Media Type**
>
> In the case of multipart entities,
>   in which one or more different    sets
>   of data are combined in a single body,
>   a "multipart" media type    field must
>   appear in the entity's header.  The
>   body must then contain    one or more
>   body parts, each preceded by **a
>   boundary delimiter line**...
>
> As stated previously, each body part is preceded by a boundary
>      delimiter line that contains the boundary delimiter.  **The boundary
>      delimiter MUST NOT appear inside any of the encapsulated parts, on a
>      line by itself or as the prefix of any line**...
>
> ...
>
> **5.1.1.  Common Syntax**
>
> The Content-Type field for
>   multipart entities requires one
>   parameter,    "boundary". **The boundary
>   delimiter line is then defined as a
>   line    consisting entirely of two
>   hyphen characters** ("-", decimal value
>   45)    followed by the boundary
>   parameter value from the Content-Type
>   header    field, optional linear
>   whitespace, and a terminating CRLF.
>
> ...
>
> **NOTE:**  Because boundary delimiters must not appear in the body parts
>      being encapsulated, a user agent must exercise care to choose a
>      unique boundary parameter value.  **The boundary parameter value 
>      [could  be] the result of an algorithm designed to
>      produce boundary delimiters with a very low probability of already
>      existing in the data to be encapsulated without having to prescan the
>      data.**  ...  The
>      simplest boundary delimiter line possible is something like "---",
>      with a closing boundary delimiter line of "-----".

Answer (score 3):

They don't mean anything.  They are just a random string that does not occur within the body of the email.  They are just used to mark where the embedded message starts and stops.